# Is there anything in BS 8888 regarding the scale of a section view?

Tags: technical-drawing, standards, drafting, drawings, cross-section

If a section view isn't sufficient enough to show all details required, can it be at a larger scale than its parent view? Is there anything in BS 8888 regarding recommended scales in section views?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**

BS 8888 specifically states that the scale should be larger than the main representation if the normal scale isn't sufficient to show the details.

This new scale must be shown adjacent to the reference letter (usually directly below the view).

[image: BS 8888 8. Scales]

[image: BS8888 12.1 and 12.2 Designation and Inscription]

Comment: I don't like to be that guy, but the text reproduced here appears to be from BS 8888:2011, which has been superseded by a more recent edition.  (I know this because I don't have access to a copy of the latest edition either, and I've been frustrated about it for some time.)

Comment: It’s fine to be that guy - I just pulled this off google. I *do* have access to the latest standard, so I’ll check, but I highly doubt that this specific guidance has changed.